# Python Opencv SolvePnP yields wrong translation vector

Tags: python, opencv, camera-calibration

I am attempting to calibrate and find the location and rotation of a single virtual camera in Blender 3d using homography. I am using Blender so that I can double check my results before I move on to the real world where that is more difficult.

I rendered ten pictures of a chess board in various locations and rotations in the view of my stationary camera. With OpenCV's Python, I used `cv2.calibrateCamera` to find the intrinsic matrix from the detected corners of the chess board in the ten images and then used that in `cv2.solvePnP` to find the extrinsic parameters(translation and rotation).

However, though the estimated parameters were close to the actual ones, there is something fishy going on. My initial estimation of the translation was `(-0.11205481,-0.0490256,8.13892491)`. The actual location was `(0,0,8.07105)`. Pretty close right?

But, when I moved and rotated the camera slightly and rerendered the images, the estimated translation became farther off. Estimated: `(-0.15933154,0.13367286,9.34058867)`. Actual: `(-1.7918,-1.51073,9.76597)`. The Z value is close, but the X and the Y are not.

I am utterly confused. If anybody can help me sort through this, I would be highly grateful. Here is the code (it's based off of the Python2 calibrate example supplied with OpenCV):

```
#imports left out
USAGE = '''
USAGE: calib.py [--save <filename>] [--debug <output path>] [--square_size] [<image mask>]
'''   

args, img_mask = getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:], '', ['save=', 'debug=', 'square_size='])
args = dict(args)
try: img_mask = img_mask[0]
except: img_mask = '../cpp/0*.png'
img_names = glob(img_mask)
debug_dir = args.get('--debug')
square_size = float(args.get('--square_size', 1.0))

pattern_size = (5, 8)
pattern_points = np.zeros( (np.prod(pattern_size), 3), np.float32 )
pattern_points[:,:2] = np.indices(pattern_size).T.reshape(-1, 2)
pattern_points *= square_size

obj_points = []
img_points = []
h, w = 0, 0
count = 0
for fn in img_names:
    print 'processing %s...' % fn,
    img = cv2.imread(fn, 0)
    h, w = img.shape[:2]
    found, corners = cv2.findChessboardCorners(img, pattern_size)        

    if found:
        if count == 0:
            #corners first is a list of the image points for just the first image.
            #This is the image I know the object points for and use in solvePnP
            corners_first =  []
            for val in corners:
                corners_first.append(val[0])                
            np_corners_first = np.asarray(corners_first,np.float64)                
        count+=1
        term = ( cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_COUNT, 30, 0.1 )
        cv2.cornerSubPix(img, corners, (5, 5), (-1, -1), term)
    if debug_dir:
        vis = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
        cv2.drawChessboardCorners(vis, pattern_size, corners, found)
        path, name, ext = splitfn(fn)
        cv2.imwrite('%s/%s_chess.bmp' % (debug_dir, name), vis)
    if not found:
        print 'chessboard not found'
        continue
    img_points.append(corners.reshape(-1, 2))
    obj_points.append(pattern_points)        

    print 'ok'

rms, camera_matrix, dist_coefs, rvecs, tvecs = cv2.calibrateCamera(obj_points, img_points, (w, h))
print "RMS:", rms
print "camera matrix:\n", camera_matrix
print "distortion coefficients: ", dist_coefs.ravel()    
cv2.destroyAllWindows()    

np_xyz = np.array(xyz,np.float64).T #xyz list is from file. Not shown here for brevity
camera_matrix2 = np.asarray(camera_matrix,np.float64)
np_dist_coefs = np.asarray(dist_coefs[:,:],np.float64)    

found,rvecs_new,tvecs_new = cv2.solvePnP(np_xyz, np_corners_first,camera_matrix2,np_dist_coefs)

np_rodrigues = np.asarray(rvecs_new[:,:],np.float64)
print np_rodrigues.shape
rot_matrix = cv2.Rodrigues(np_rodrigues)[0]

def rot_matrix_to_euler(R):
    y_rot = asin(R[2][0]) 
    x_rot = acos(R[2][2]/cos(y_rot))    
    z_rot = acos(R[0][0]/cos(y_rot))
    y_rot_angle = y_rot *(180/pi)
    x_rot_angle = x_rot *(180/pi)
    z_rot_angle = z_rot *(180/pi)        
    return x_rot_angle,y_rot_angle,z_rot_angle

print "Euler_rotation = ",rot_matrix_to_euler(rot_matrix)
print "Translation_Matrix = ", tvecs_new
```

Comment: I have the same problem, I'm using a different method though. I hope someone here knows the answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14444433/calculate-camera-world-position-with-opencv-python

Comment: you don't need your own rot_matrix_to_euler, Rodrigues does that for you

Comment: Well, b_m, then looks like we are in the same boat haha. Hopefully someone will be able to help us out. How do I get the euler angles from Rodrigues directly? The 3x1 rotation vector is not the same as the euler angles for me. Also, are my inputs into solvePnP correct? Is that how you use the output from calibratecamera?

Comment: @user1713402 sorry I got totally confused, you are right the 3x1 returned by solvePnP is not euler angles sorry.  My recommendation is that you find yourself a specific example where solvePnP is giving unexpected results.  List the 3d and 2d coordinates of the points going in, and your camera matrix, and why you think the output of solvePnP is wrong.

Comment: Haha no prob. I was unable to find any good examples on the web that might relate to this problem. I can post the data I am working with if that would help any. The reason I think that it is not producing the result I expect is because it should be outputing the location and rotation of the blender camera. Since I can find this in blender, I can compare it with my results. They do not seem to correspond as I would think.

Comment: yes, please post your data :)

Comment: Can anyone tell me what xyz is? Isn't it the obj points ?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I think you may be thinking of `tvecs_new` as the camera position. Slightly confusingly that is not the case! In fact it is the position of the world origin in camera co-ords. To get the camera pose in the object/world co-ords, I believe you need to

```py
-np.matrix(rotation_matrix).T * np.matrix(tvecs_new)
```

And you can get the Euler angles using `cv2.decomposeProjectionMatrix(P)[-1]` where `P` is the `[r|t]` 3 by 4 extrinsic matrix.

I found [this](https://ksimek.github.com/2012/08/22/extrinsic/) to be a pretty good article about the intrinsics and extrinsics...

Comment: Wow! Works like a charm! Thank you so much. I have not gotten to the article yet (I plan to), but this certainly fixed the results. I'm a little confused what you mean by "its the position of the world origin in camera co-ords". Any chance you could briefly elaborate on that? What are camera co-ords? Also, the Euler angles obtained with the decompose correspond with my calculated euler angles (im going to stick with opencvs code though)

Comment: @user1713402 - Cool :) . The `camera coordinate system` is the cameras cartesian coordinate system, it moves with the camera, and the camera is always at the origin, the z-axis is the direction of camera view, y  is up the image, and x is to the right. Whereas the world co-ord system is static, and the camera moves within it. [Heres](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/695043/how-does-one-convert-world-coordinates-to-camera-coordinates) another question that explains it a bit more.

Comment: Great! That makes sense! Thanks once again

Comment: this works great , but euler values in x and y doesnt fit in blender cordinate system