# OpenCV: unable to get correct euler angles for calibration of single camera

Tags: python, opencv, camera-calibration

I posted a few weeks ago because I was having trouble getting the correct translation vector in opencv with python when I was calibrating my camera ([Python Opencv SolvePnP yields wrong translation vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14515200/python-opencv-solvepnp-yields-wrong-translation-vector)) Though, that was solved, I am not having trouble getting the correct rotation for my camera. The odd part is the translation vector is correct. Is there something that need to be done to the rvecs output of solvepnp to get the camera's rotation in global coordinates? I tried converting rvecs to the rotation matrix with cv2.rodrigues and then converting that to euler angles using cv2.decomposeProjectionMatrix.

Thanks so much again

Answer (score 0):

I believe the default rotation of the camera in Blender was different from opencv and this was causing problems. I fixed this and it seems to work

Comment: How did you fix it ? since am having same issue