# OpenCV: transform point clouds to leftmost camera's coordinate system

Tags: python, opencv

I am doing structure from motion from multiple images using OpenCV. I have 8 images, and I have generated 3D point clouds for each pair of images (img1&2, img2&3, img3&4 etc.). I know that each individual 3D point cloud is correct because they look good when displayed in VTK / OpenGL.

My cameras are (roughly) calibrated, using EXIF metadata for the focal length and the center of the image as the principal point.

How do I transform each of these 3D point clouds into the 3D coordinate system of the leftmost camera?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you have your point-clouds stored in a PCL compatible format; then you can simply use [pcl::transformPointCloud](http://docs.pointclouds.org/trunk/group__common.html#ga1b1184df8fe618d2014518aa262fa591).. If not, then you will need to implement your own based on the source code given in [transforms.hpp](http://docs.pointclouds.org/trunk/transforms_8hpp_source.html)..

HTH

EDIT:

Please refer to slides 16-19 in [this presentation](http://www.cse.psu.edu/~rcollins/CSE486/lecture12.pdf). The transformation model is,

`P_c = R_c (P_w - C)`

This is the mathematical form of the the transformation given in my previous link.

Comment: My points are stored in a text file with x,y,z coord for one point on each line.

Comment: If they have x, y and z coordinates, then you can apply this function to them (you don't even need to build PCL, just use the implementation in your own function)..

Comment: I'm using OpenCV's python bindings though, so would that still be possible? It seems to me like I would have to translate the source code to Python.

Comment: Yeah, PCL and OpenCV are built entirely on C++.. It shouldn't be that hard to write the equivalent Python code, though.

Comment: I see. Does that mean there's no OpenCV function I can call to transform the 3D coordinate system? I've been trying to use solvePnP to get the camera position but I can't figure out which coordinate system it's relative to.

Comment: solvePnP is used to get the object pose from 2D correspondences. You need to map the pose defined in one coordinate system to another. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/695043/how-does-one-convert-world-coordinates-to-camera-coordinates) would be a helpful resource too.

Comment: Yep, thanks for the link! I was also wondering if I could use estimateAffine3D to do the mapping?